# How to QA test Azure Data Factory?

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I am from QA team. My dev team has created pipelines in Azure Data factory. They want me to QA test them. I need to write manual test cases and later after some time I also need to automate this. Please guide me how/ what to test using manual test case. Also suggest me automation tool for later stage that I should use to create automation test cases. Selenium?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at this blog post, it really helped me when I started with testing in ADF: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karang/2018/11/18/azure-data-factory-v2-pipeline-functional-testing/

You won't be able to test everything in Data Factory, at most you can check if connection strings are correct, queries dont break, objects are present (in database or blob storage or whatever you data source is), etc. Testing if the end result of a pipeline is what you intended to do, is highly dependent of the use case and most of the time its not worth it.

I'm not an expert, but as far as I know, Selenium is used to automate browser testing related stuff. Here you won't need a complex framework, you can get away with using a Powershell script as described in the blog post, but you also have other options like Python, .NET, REST api.

Hope this helped!!

Answer (score 0):

Our Q&A team just changes the settings to see the pipeline behavior, uses not normal data to push trough the pipeline, different time zones and timestamps and etc.. But the majority of the test are the final pipeline results.

Answer (score 0):

I have used a Specflow project (https://specflow.org/) and supporting .Net code to set up the tests and execute the pipeline on test files held in the project. You can automate this into your build or release pipelines.